# creating entry into ladp directory using python

Tags: python, mysql, ldap

I am trying to create entry into LDAP using python it gives me error {'info': 'no global superior knowledge', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform'}
following is my code for this

```
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist
fname="dayanand"
lname="dayanand"
username="dayanand"
employee_num='102'
domain="gmail.com"
base_dn="xyz"
l = ldap.initialize("ldap://localhost")
l.simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=somnath,dc=zankar,dc=org","zankar")
user_dn = "cn=admin,dc=somnath,dc=org"
user_attrs = {}
#user_attrs['objectClass'] = \
#          ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user']
user_attrs['cn'] = fname + ' ' + lname
#user_attrs['userPrincipalName'] = username + '@' + domain
#user_attrs['sAMAccountName'] = username
user_attrs['givenName'] = fname
user_attrs['sn'] = lname
user_attrs['displayName'] = fname + ' ' + lname
#user_attrs['userAccountControl'] = '514'
user_attrs['mail'] = username + '@host.com'
#user_attrs['employeeID'] = employee_num
user_attrs['homeDirectory'] = '\\\\server\\' + username
#user_attrs['homeDrive'] = 'H:'
#user_attrs['scriptPath'] = 'logon.vbs'
user_ldif = modlist.addModlist(user_attrs)

# Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using modlist-module
ldif = modlist.addModlist(user_attrs)

# Do the actual synchronous add-operation to the ldapserver
try:
   l.add_s(user_dn,ldif)
except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
    print "Error adding new user: %s" % error_message
```

Comment: Could you pleae write the exact error output ?

Answer (score 0):

What does the directory tree look like in your LDAP instance?  I ask because you're trying to bind to dc=somnath,dc=zankar,dc=org:

```
l.simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=somnath,dc=zankar,dc=org","zankar")
```

But you're trying to add something to dc=somnath,dc=org:

```
user_dn = "cn=admin,dc=somnath,dc=org"
```

And the error 'no global superior knowledge' can be seen when you are trying to add an entry to a part of the directory that does not exist.

You could create a new base DN of dc=somnath,dc=org, or try to add an entry to dc=somnath,dc=zanker,dc=org. **NOTE** try to add an entry that is not cn=admin, since that presumably already exists, as you are using it to bind() to the service.